# NoSuchMethodError using jackson-dataformat-csv

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm using jackson-dataformat-csv to read a csv file in, and I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError when trying to parse the mappingIterator with the line

```
MyRecord record = (MyRecord) it.nextValue();
```

of this snipped (slightly modified, ex handling removed)

```
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(MyRecord.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    MappingIterator<Entry> it = csvMapper.reader(MyRecord.class)
        .with(schema).readValues(filename);

    List<MyRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    while (it.hasNextValue()) {
        MyRecord record = (MyRecord) it.nextValue();
        records.add(record);
    }
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues/49
My issue is very close to this one, except I've already tried the solution of making sure jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-csv, and jackson-annotations are all the same version (2.8).  It looks like there is a 2.9 that changes things now, but at my company I don't have access to 2.9.  Is there some other package I could have a conflict in?

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.allocCharBuffer(II)[C
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.TextBuffer.findBuffer(TextBuffer.java:160)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.TextBuffer.emptyAndGetCurrentSegment(TextBuffer.java:404)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.CsvDecoder.nextString(CsvDecoder.java:607)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._handleNextEntry(CsvParser.java:678)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser.nextToken(CsvParser.java:523)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.nextValue(MappingIterator.java:189)
```

Comment: How is your 'it' variable defined?

Comment: Sorry that was a pretty terrible post- I meant to at least paste the actual stack trace... I've added the code context I should have as well now.  I'm not sure what the "(II)[C" represent in the error message, but if I inspect the code of BufferRecycler I do see several allocCharBuffer methods.

Comment: Are you using maven? If so, try running mvn dependency:tree in your project folder so you can see if the dependencies are really right. This has every leads to a library version problem.

Comment: My company uses an in-house system for distributed dependency management- but it does seem like it was some glitch either with that or the eclipse workspace.  I created a new workspace and it seems to work fine now.  Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score -1):

This has been solved, although I'm still not sure about the root cause.  I believe the root cause may be specific to my own use case (my company uses it's own in-house systems for local development workspaces as well as dependency management.  I ended up creating a new local (and eclipse) workspace and this same code seems to be working fine now.